# How to find the longest memo field in any table of my database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to find the longest memo field in any table of my database? It would be easy to do this for just one table, but I want to do it across the whole database.

Can I do it with a single SQL query?

Comment: (Minor aside: it's best not to add commentary on downvotes to posts. The main reason for this is that most readers do not sign in or vote, and thus material about this meta-topic is not relevant to them, and is a distraction from the technical material. Also, the voter will usually already have gone, and thus this question very rarely elicits answers. You can put it in comments if you wish, but it's still probably a waste of time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have dynamic table names in queries.

You have to get the list of tables (with `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'` or something like that) and execute one query for each table (and for each column).

(SQLite has almost no programming constructs; you have to do this in the language from which you are accessing the database.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(someField)) FROM someTable;
```